# How to make both insertion and fetching in O(1) at any position?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I am trying to make both insertion and fetching of data from any position and I need a Data structure which can provide me an access for this in O(1)

I have gone through this link : https://dzone.com/articles/gaplist-lightning-fast-list

Answer (score 0):

The native arrays provide insertion and fetching in constant O(1) time since arrays are always a contiguous block of memory. Unless you have some other requirements like a key value pair storage or something else, basic arrays are still the fastest data structures to insert data and then fetch from any position.

**Edit**

So after reading the question properly again, a way in which this can be done is by using a HashMap where the key is the position and value is the value to be stored at that position.
But I personally won't consider this a good approach. I will update this answer if I get something later!

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you cannot insert an item between two other values without moving all items around.

Comment: Native arrays don't provide insertion at all. They provide setting an element in O(1).